# "sudo chmod 666 ttyUSB0" in c++

Tags: c++

I have a program to Open, Write and Read ttyUSB0; I have the problem that I have to do the comand `sudo chmod 666 ttyUSB0` everyday, Is it possible that I insert this comand in c++????

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system

Comment: bitttcoinn i am thinking of bittcoinn

Comment: But would it not be better to stop whatever it is that resets the mode from resetting it?

Comment: @MatsPetersson: on a modern Linux system the proper solution would be to create an udev rule about permissions to this device. Whenever the USB device gets attached, the udev system would create a `/dev/` entry with the correct permissions.

Answer (score 3):

Your original problem to allow access to a serial port (/dev/ttyUSBxxx) could also be resolved giving the needed capabilities to your specific program on your system.
Look into [setcap](http://linux.die.net/man/8/setcap)
Then you could do something like:

```
setcap cap_sys_tty_config+ep /path/to/your/program
```

I am not sure what capabilities exactly you do need (haven't tried it).

Note: The device-node is IMHO something of the system with permissions defided by the owner of the system I would be unhappy if I ran a program and it changed permissions of files and/or devicenodes on my system. 
The canonical way is to add the user to a group, for instance the group `dialout` has tty access permissions on debian.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Normally you could call the `chmod()` C function, but you seem to need `sudo`, so:

```
system("sudo -S chmod 666 ttyUSB0 <<< PASSWORD")
```

But sure to check the return value.  Zero means success.

Comment: does system work with the command requiring user input? (e.g. requiring the password?)

Comment: If `sudo` requires a password, so will this.  You can set up your system to allow `sudo` without a password but that's not a programming question, it's a system administration one suitable for SuperUser.  Or maybe you can reconsider whether `sudo` is necessary, or perhaps the entire command isn't needed?  You could also put it in root's `cron`.

Comment: I require password, can I introduce the password in c++??

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to use `sudo -S` with a hard-coded password.  This is probably a bad idea for security, but you can do it if you want to!

Comment: `sudo` password protection might be implemented in terms of reading characters from the terminal device (`/dev/ptyXXX` or what have you), rather than in terms of the general-purpose POSIX `stdin` I/O stream.

Comment: @TadeuszA.Kadłubowski: right, that's why you have to use `sudo -S`, so it will read from `stdin`.